# How to mount a persistent disk in a different zone

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have several servers in different zones in the same region. I'd like to mount a persistent disk on all of them to have a central location for some scripts that keep everything up to date on each of them. Has anyone done this before?

I know you can't attach persistent disks to compute instances in another zone, but is there another way of mounting them? Would I need to attach it to one instance and share it from there? Or is there another way of doing this that would work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know you can't attach persistent disks to compute instances in
>   another zone, but is there another way of mounting them? Would I need
>   to attach it to one instance and share it from there?

Google does allow attaching persistent disks to multiple machines with the caveat that it's mounted read-only. If you need to mount across zones, though, the best bet is to mount the disk *once* on a single server and then share/export that storage to all of your other machines.

In Linux world, you'd use NFS for this and on Windows, CIFS/SMB.